# How can I write a program in Japanese in Pascal?

Tags: pascal

I'm teaching myself Pascal and thought mixing Pascal with Japanese sounded like a really good idea the other day, but it appears Pascal only accepts Japanese characters some of the time, and I don't really know why it accepts them at all. Is there something I need to include to allow writing in Japanese with Free Pascal?

Comment: Did you try to google, "encoding for Pascal"?

Comment: I didn't think of it. It looks like I have some reading to do now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which Pascal, and you don't describe acceptance. As identifier or literals in source code, on standard input, as literal?

Delphi D2009 and higher support unicode identifiers in their utf8 sources.

Free Pascal hasn't implemented this yet. It does allow utf8 source encoding though, and thus unicode literals.